pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx' error using Kivy's FileChooser, Python 3.12, Windows 10, kivy 2.3.0
Using Kivy 2.3.0, Python 3.12, on a Windows 10 computer.  On starting up the app I get error messages like this (all of them are below):
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\DumpStack.log.tmp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')

I believe this has to do with the FileCooser.  It is accessing system files that it can't deal with, before my filtering of those files kicks in.  In my kv file, in the FileChooserListView:  I have this set up:
FileChooserListView:
        id: filechooser
        filters: root.filters
        filter_dirs: root.filter_dirs  # Bind the filter function for directories
        filter_func: root.filter_files  # Bind the filter function here
        dirselect: root.dirselect
        multiselect: False
        show_hidden: False  # Hide hidden and system files
    BoxLayout:

And it the app I have the file and directory filtering set up.  But I don't see that they are being accessed, as I put print statements in them.
class FileChooserScreen(Screen):
    filters = ObjectProperty(['*'])
    dirselect = BooleanProperty(False)
    file_type = None
    last_path = StringProperty("")
    
    def filter_files(self, folder, filename):
        print(f"filter_files called for: {filename}")
        """Custom filter to exclude specific system files and handle permission errors."""
        system_files = ['hiberfil.sys', 'pagefile.sys', 'swapfile.sys', 'DumpStack.log.tmp']
        # system_files = os.listdir(folder)
    
        try:
            # Exclude system files based on their name
            if filename in system_files:
                print(f"Excluding system file: {filename}")
                return False
            return True  # Allow the file if it's not a system file
        except (OSError, PermissionError) as e:
            # Handle permission errors gracefully and skip the file
            print(f"Error accessing {filename}: {e}")
            return False  # Exclude files that raise access errors
    
    def filter_dirs(self, folder, filename):
        """Filter out system directories and handle permission errors."""
        system_dirs = ['$Recycle.Bin', 'System Volume Information', 'Config.Msi', 'Windows', 'Program Files',
                       'Program Files (x86)']
    
        try:
            if filename in system_dirs or filename.startswith('$') or filename.startswith('.'):
                print(f"Excluding system file: {filename}")
                return False  # Exclude system directories and hidden ones
            return True  # Include other directories
        except (OSError, PermissionError) as e:
            print(f"Error accessing directory {filename}: {e}")
            return False  # Exclude directories that raise access errors

I called them in an on_entry:
 def on_enter(self):
    # Set up filters for files and directories when the screen is entered
    # print("Setting filters in on_enter for FileChooser")
    # self.ids.filechooser.filter_func = self.filter_files
    # self.ids.filechooser.filter_dirs = self.filter_dirs

    # Set the last path or default to Documents folder
    main_screen = self.manager.get_screen('main')
    file_type_last_path = main_screen.last_paths.get(self.file_type, "")
    self.ids.filechooser.path = file_type_last_path if file_type_last_path else get_documents_path()

And I even tried to call them much earlier in the APP, and I did see my message print out saying the filters where set, but no luck same issues.  I commented out the on_start below, but did try that code too.
class ImageDownloaderApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(HelpScreen(name='help'))
        sm.add_widget(FileChooserScreen(name='filechooser'))
        sm.add_widget(RunningScreen(name='running'))
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
    # Access the filechooser screen and set filters after the app starts
    file_chooser_screen = self.root.get_screen('filechooser')

    # Set the filters for files and directories
    file_chooser_screen.ids.filechooser.filter_func = file_chooser_screen.filter_files
    file_chooser_screen.ids.filechooser.filter_dirs = file_chooser_screen.filter_dirs

    # Optionally set default filters for file types (e.g., CSV, PDF)
    # file_chooser_screen.ids.filechooser.filters = ['*.csv', '*.pdf']
    file_chooser_screen.ids.filechooser.show_hidden = False  # Hide hidden files by default
    print("Filters and custom file filtering set after startup!")

# Load the KV file (this should stay as it is)
Builder.load_file('image_downloader.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ImageDownloaderApp().run()

Here are the errors:
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\.....\.kivy\logs\kivy_24-10-10_20.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.4.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.7.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.3.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Git\.....\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Git\.....\.venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 195 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.2127'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 31.0.101.2127'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\DumpStack.log.tmp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\hiberfil.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.....\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\pagefile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\swapfile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\DumpStack.log.tmp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\hiberfil.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\........\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\pagefile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] unable to access to <\swapfile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\DumpStack.log.tmp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\hiberfil.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\pagefile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\swapfile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\DumpStack.log.tmp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\........\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\hiberfil.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\pagefile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\........\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[ERROR  ] [unable to access to <C]\swapfile.sys>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Git\.......\.venv\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\filechooser.py", line 180, in is_hidden
    return GetFileAttributesExW(fn)[0] & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.error: (32, 'GetFileAttributesEx', 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.')
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] Window is now on display 1
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] Window is now on display 0


I had to change the "show_hidden: False"  to "show_hidden: True" in my FileChooserListView kv file setup below.  I believe the show_hidden process was conflicting with my other filtering, and that caused the issue.  I have reproduced it with example Kivy code, my code and other examples.
There where other errors in my code, but this fixed the issue!
filter_dirs is a BooleanProperty
Also there is no such thing as "filters_func".  I found I can pass a list to
filters: [root.filter_files]   # Wrap the filter function in a list
Here is the bad:
FileChooserListView:
    id: filechooser
    filters: root.filters
    filter_dirs: root.filter_dirs  # Bind the filter function for 
                                             directories
    filter_func: root.filter_files  # Bind the filter function here
    dirselect: root.dirselect
    multiselect: False
    show_hidden: False  # Hide hidden and system files

And the working:
FileChooserListView:
    id: filechooser
    filters: [root.filter_files]
    dirselect: root.dirselect  # This returns a True/False direct select a folder?
    multiselect: False
    show_hidden: True  # Hide hidden and system files

A few other changes to my code including this import:
from fnmatch import fnmatch


class FileChooserScreen(Screen):
   filters = ObjectProperty(['*'])  # Default filter on, to let all files throught
   dirselect = BooleanProperty(False)  # Default to file selection mode
   file_type = StringProperty('*')  # Track the current file type filter
   last_path = StringProperty("")  # To store the last selected path




    def filter_files(self, folder, filename):
        """Custom filter function to filter files based on type and exclude specific files."""
        system_files = ['hiberfil.sys', 'pagefile.sys', 'swapfile.sys', 'DumpStack.log.tmp']

        # Filter out system files
        if filename in system_files:
            return False

        # Apply file type filtering based on the current filter setting
        from fnmatch import fnmatch
        if not any(fnmatch(filename, pattern) for pattern in self.filters):
            return False

        return True



    def set_file_type(self, file_type):
        # Set the file type (csv, pdf, folder) and adjust filters
        self.file_type = file_type
        if file_type == 'csv':
            self.filters = ['*.csv']
            self.dirselect = False
        elif file_type == 'pdf':
            self.filters = ['*.pdf']
            self.dirselect = False
        elif file_type == 'folder':
            self.filters = ["*/"]
            self.dirselect = True
        else:  # Added this catch all
            self.filters = ['*']  # Show all files
        # Update the visibility of the folder options in the UI
        folder_options = self.ids.folder_options
        if self.dirselect:
            folder_options.opacity = 1  # Show folder creation options
        else:
            folder_options.opacity = 0  # Hide folder creation options

